# XML and XSLT table

Tags: xml, xslt

```
Need to convert this xml to a table
```

[example of a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaNu8.png)

here is a fragment of the xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='rgz.xsl'?>
    <hiblock>
        <page num="0">
            <name>Assignment by options</name>      
            <variants>
                <sequence variant="3">
                    <name>Hatch Numbers</name>
                    <items>
                        <item><num color="#336600">1</num><val>2</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#330000">2</num><val>1</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#330066">3</num><val>3</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#660033">4</num><val>4</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#006633">5</num><val>7</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#000033">6</num><val>11</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#663300">7</num><val>18</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#003300">8</num><val>29</val></item>
                        <item><num color="#003366">9</num><val>47</val></item>
                    </items>
                </sequence>
            </variants>
        </page>
    </hiblock>
```

I will also be glad if you tell me how to sort a similar table, but in which there are "order" pictures

Comment: Do you know the target format (e.g. is it an HTML table you want to create or an XSL-FO table later to be rendered as a PDF? In the end you should know the markup you want to create and show your attempt to use XSLT to create that markup, it seems you want to map each `num` element to a cell in the first table row and each `val` to a cell in the second table row.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.